# Symfony 2 Doctrine 2 one to many relationship not returning data

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I got back to doctrine after a while. I have some problem with doctrine and symfony which I can't figure out at all, why it could be. A help would be nice.

I've got two entities:
1. Category:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Items", mappedBy="category")
 */
private $items;


public function __construct() 
{
    $this->items = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}



/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 *
 * @param Items $items
 * @return Category
 */
public function addItem(Items $item)
{
    $this->items[] = $item;

    return $this;
}

/**
 *
 * @param Items $item
 */
public function removeItem(Items $item)
{
    $this->items->removeElement($item);
}

/**
 * @return Items
 */
public function getItems()
{
    return $this->items;
}
```

And Second is: Items

```
  /**
  * @var integer
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
  */
 private $id;

 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="items")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 private $category;


 /**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
 public function getId()
 {
    return $this->id;
 }

 /**
 * Set category
 *
 * @param Category $category
 * @return Items
 */
 public function setCategory(Category $category = null)
 {
    $this->category = $category;

    return $this;
 }

 /**
  * Get category
  *
  * @return Category 
  */
 public function getCategory()
 {
    return $this->category;
 }
```

Now in Controller, I'm simply trying to retrieve items via categories:

```
    $categories = $em->getRepository('Category')->findAll();  
    //just example 
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        print_r($category->getItems());
    }
```

Should $category->getItems() return the Items of that category? Or I'm in illusion that it should work? Please suggest.

It returns null at the moment but not errors although there is data in database.

The table structure is:

```
  CREATE TABLE `category` (

 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And

```
 CREATE TABLE `items` (

 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

 `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

  KEY `fk_category` (`category_id`),

 CONSTRAINT `fk_category` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `Category` (`id`)

 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Thanks

Comment: It should work. What is the problem? Are there any errors? What is the result of printing `$category->getItems()`?

Comment: Thanks for getting back Shad. It returns nothing. Although, there is data in the database.

Comment: have you tried to put `public function __construct()
    {
        $this->items = new ArrayCollection();
    }` inside the category entity?

Comment: It's already there. Sorry I had ommitted that part when I did paste here.

Comment: I've tested it locally and it worked. Should return `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection` object

Comment: Which is not nice, as it doesn't work although the code is same for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you post `var_dump($categories);`?

Comment: Yea. And items is a property of $categories which is blank (null).

Comment: Are you sure your DB is okay?

Comment: I have put the table structure in question, as formatting does not look good here in comments.

Comment: Maybe try the opposite. Instead of trying to get items for category, try to fetch some random item and see if there's category properly attached: `$categories = $em->getRepository('Items')->find($some_id);`

Comment: Yes, it does return proper category object.

Comment: Stupid question but have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: It is good question. Yea. Many times. I was doing that just earlier. :)

Comment: I don't see any reason for this to not work.. I'm out of ideas

Comment: Thanks for spending time on this though. Hopefully, Someone will look at it and will be able to say that there is one more thing to try.

Comment: which version of symfony/doctrine are you using?

Comment: 2.4 Symfony. Just downloaded last week. Doctrine 2.2, (I believe 2.2.3 to be specific).

Comment: Is it dev environment? Check profilers db panel and see the queries that been run

Comment: It doesn't touch the items table at all, runs select ... from category once.

Comment: Should be like this: `SELECT t0.id AS id1 FROM category t0` `SELECT t0.id AS id1, [...] FROM items t0 WHERE t0.category_id = ?`. I just copied your code and it worked instantly.

Comment: It is just doing select t0.id as id1 from category t0 unfortunately.
Is that what is does to you?

Comment: Maybe try to use console and run `doctrine:schema:validate`

Comment: [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.

Comment: I will look at after a while in fresh mind again. Please post any idea come into mind. Ta.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the category of the item when you add it otherwise it will be saved in the database as `NULL` rather than the category id.

```
/**
 *
 * @param Items $items
 * @return Category
 */
public function addItem(Items $item)
{
    $item->setCategory($this);
    $this->items[] = $item;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Qoop, thanks for getting back. But it's not null because of the way data is added. Plus, I tested by adding data to database manually, it is still not working.

Comment: My problem was very similar: You only could access one side of the relation (item => category), but category => items was empty. The explicit usage of "setCategory" solved it for me, because it "tells" the other side, that there is one to take care of.

Answer (score 1):

2 years later.. I'm also looking to make this work with the latest Symfony and Doctrine and by $category->getItems()

What I had to do is, in your case:

Controller:

```
$items = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Items')->findByCategory($category);
```

For some reason ->getItems() is empty.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($category->getItems());
```

instead of

```
print_r($category->getItems());
```

i face the same issue when i tried `dump()` function for some reason it doesn't dump results